# Complex integration by substitution

Tags: calculus, complex-integration, substitution

Integrate $ f(z) $ counterclockwise around the unit circle.
$$ f(z) = 1/(4z-3) $$

---

My solution

C(contour) : $ z(t) = \cos{t} + i\sin{t} = e^{it}, 0<t\leq 2\pi $

$$ \oint_C \frac{1}{4z-3} dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{4e^{it}-3} \frac{dz}{dt} dt = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{4e^{it}-3}ie^{it} $$
substitute $ u=e^{it}, du = ie^{it} dt $
$$ \oint_C \frac{1}{4z-3} dz = \int_1^1 \frac{1}{4u-3}du = 0 $$

---

But as you know, this answer is wrong. According to the Cauchy's integral formula, the answer must be $ \frac{i\pi}{2} $.

I cannot find an error in my way. I guess substitution $ u=e^{it} $ is wrong, but I don't know exactly. Why did I reach wrong result?

Comment: It makes sense that, once you change the limits of the integral, it would evaluate to zero. The issue must lie here. I do not believe that substitutions work well with complex numbers, but this is only a vague recollection. I shall consult with my complex analysis texts and get back to you.

Comment: I want to know why substitution do not works well with complex line integration.. can you let me know exact reason?

Comment: Sorry I am traveling; will answer as soon as I get to a computer.

Comment: I have solved this problem just now. When I substitute u=e^it, integration become complex integration from 1 to 1 again. Complex integration depends on integration path so integration of variable u needs a path. This was the mistake.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. I couldn't quite put my figure on it, but yes that is definitely the issue